# Data in column cell to be link to another page. KendoUI grid widget

Tags: kendo-ui

I am researching KendoUI library to use it in Asp.Net Mvc 3 project. This is an example of the grid widget populated with some local data. I need to make some of the columns to be links that lead to another page of the application. For example, if You click Deposit you should be navigated to the "Home/Deposit" View. How can this be done? Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is Fiddler sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/MwHNd/245/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use template column, here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/aNCV4/11/

Comment: Yes, I used it like this:

 columns: [
                    {
                        template: '<a href="FranchiseDetails/#=Id#">#=FolderName#</a>',
                        field: "FolderName",
                        title: "Name",
                        width: 100
                    }

Thank You for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links you may find helpful:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

http://bristowe.com/blog/2012/5/9/connecting-the-kendo-ui-datasource-to-remote-data.html

Also, here is a solution to create a linked column mostly in Kendo JavaScript:

```js
(function(myPage, $, undefined) {
 
    var IDS = {
        ...
        myGrid: "#my-grid",
 
        ...
 
        selectedMasterkey: "#selected-master-key",
        selectedChildkey: "#selected-child-key",
    };
 
    var Grids = {
        MyGrid: null,
    };
 
    function initMyGrid() {
        $(IDS.myGrid).kendoGrid({
            selectable: true,
            scrolable: true,
            sortable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "Key", title: "key", width: "60%" },
                { field: "Weight", title: "Weight", width: "20%" },
                { field: "Link", title: "Link", width: "20%", template:"<a href="../MyData.mvc/Index?key=#=KEY#">#=KEY#</a>"} <!-- This is the hyperlinked column -->
            ],
 
            change: function() {
                var selectedDataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
                if (PageState.Selected.ChildKey != selectedDataItem.KEY) {
                    PageState.Selected.ChildKey = selectedDataItem.KEY;
                    myGridSelectionChanged();
                }
            },
 
            ...
 
        });
 
        Grids.MyGrid = $(IDS.myGrid).data('kendoGrid');
 
        Grids.MyGrid .element.on("dblclick", "tbody>tr", "dblclick", function(e) {
            var dbClickedKey = Grids.MyGrid .dataItem($(this)).KEY;
            window.open('../MyData.mvc/Index?key='+dbClickedKey,'_blank');
        });
        bindMyGrid();
    }
 
    function bindMyGrid() {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "MyData",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function(data) {
                    return {
                        myDataId: getQueryStringParameterByName('mydataid')
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function(response) {
                    return response;
 
                },
                total: function(response) {
                    return response.length;
                },
                parse: function(response) {
                    var myDataList= [];
                    $.each(response, function(i, key) {
                        myDataList.push({ "KEY": key });
                    });
                    return myDataList;
                },
            },
        });
        dataSource.fetch();
        dataSource.view();
        Grids.MyGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
    ...
 
    myPage.initialize = function() {
        initMyGrid();
    }
 
}(window.myPage = window.myPage || {}, jQuery));
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
         columns.Bound(c => c.Deposit).ClientTemplate("<a target='_blank' href='Home/Deposit'>#=Deposit#</a>").Title("Deposit");
```